# Best way to join this into a temp table and inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wondering the best way to put this into a temp table and then join it.

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT LocId
FROM dbo.Locations WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceSystem = @SourceSystem 
AND LocId IN (SELECT ListVal
FROM etopsuser.fnParseListToTable(@LocIdList, ';')) AND IsHot = 1)
BEGIN
```

Specifically trying to do it on this line of code

```sql
    (SELECT ListVal
FROM etopsuser.fnParseListToTable(@LocIdList, ';')) AND IsHot = 1)
```

The NOLOCK is unrelated

Comment: Anything using `NOLOCK` is *rarely* the "best way" unless you're happy with possible incorrect and inconsistent results..

Comment: I am ok with that, I am getting the correct data. That is to prevent locks when multiple of the same things are being queried at the same time.

Comment: *"That is to prevent locks when multiple of the same things are being queried at the same time."* You know that *isn't* what `NOLOCK` does, right? Despite its name `NOLOCK` does not stop locks being taken.

Comment: Ok. I'll be sure to tell that to all the senior devs who use NOLOCK's on literally every piece of code I have to touch. lol. I guess its to prevent other processes from locking it.

Comment: I'd suggest pointing them here, @Andre: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). As "senior" developers they should know better than to spam `NOLOCK`, and if they do, the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @Larnu Awesome tyvm for the advice/ link. I will certainly do my research on it and try and think of some better methods to talk to them about. The NOLOCKS are in literally every proc this program uses and we do occasionally have dirty reads.

Comment: If the seniors don't understand NOLOCK, the perhaps it is time to start using table variables to pass an "array" of values to a procedure. And SQL Server now supports [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is likely more efficient than your custom-written split function.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for the advice. I am what you would most people would probably call a noob but I will definitely be researching you and Larnus advice to start using better methods regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a temporary table just like any other table from a `select`:

```
SELECT ListVal
INTO #templist
FROM etopsuser.fnParseListToTable(@LocIdList, ';');
```

Then you would use it as:

```
SELECT l.LocId
FROM dbo.Locations l JOIN
     #templist tl
     ON l.LocId = tl.Listval
WHERE l.SourceSystem = @SourceSystem AND l.IsHot = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to pass a list into a procedure is to use a Table Valued Parameter**

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.List AS TABLE (ListVal varchar(255));
```

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Locations l
    WHERE l.SourceSystem = @SourceSystem 
    AND l.LocId IN (
        SELECT ll.ListVal
        FROM @LocIdList ll
    ) AND IsHot = 1)
```

> Notes: Always use table references on every column, especially if subqueries are involved. Never use `NOLOCK` unless you are prepared for incorrect results. `EXISTS` ignores its `SELECT`, so `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL` is standard.

Then you can pass in the table variable either from client code depending on language, or in T-SQL like this

```sql
DECLARE @list dbo.List;
INSERT @list (ListVal)
VALUES ('SomeValue');

EXEC YourProc @LocIdList = @list;
```